# Missing step in downloading Ruby and crerating a new Ruby on Rails project on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am starting a new project that we decided to try out with Rails ... so I just installed Ruby via the [Windows Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/) and then, as is suggested on the Rails website, I run

```
gem install rails
rails new path/to/your/new/application
```

(replacing the path with my real project name) and I get the error that it failed complaining about JSON and that it can't build native extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby on Rails home page](http://rubyonrails.org/download/) tells you to install Ruby.

On the [installer download page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) it says

> If you don’t know what version to install and you’re getting started
>   with Ruby, we recommend you use Ruby 2.1.X installers

Ignore that. On the Ruby on Rails home page it says what version to install.

> We recommend Ruby 2.2 or newer for use with Rails.

Then the Ruby on Rails home page says to run the following commands:

```
gem install rails

rails new path/to/your/new/application
cd path/to/your/new/application
rails server
```

The above won't work. The new rails project will fail.

What the steps above don't tell you is that, after running the installer, download and install [the DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

So ...

- Download version of Ruby recommended on Ruby home page
- Install Rails via `gem install rails`
- **Download** DevKit
- Then create Rails project by running last three commands above.